# Building a query which uses percentages to select from certain requirements

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I am new to rails and programming in general. I am having a problem building a certain functionality, especially because I don't really know what I am looking/ googling for.

Lets say I have restaurants with a column "rating". The scale is from 1 to 3. Now, I want to build a query which selects records from this table based on the rating. What I want to do is: 60% of the records should have a rating of 3, 30% a rating of 2, and 10% a rating of 1. Furthermore, these records should be selected randomly. Does anyone understand what I am trying to do? I'd really appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction!

Thank you so much.

Comment: Can you add a query you use to select restaurants just with a given rating so I can give a more useful answer?

Comment: it sounds pointless, at least in the context you've described. Why would you need this?

Comment: @AndreyDeineko because that might be the business logic required. Ever heard of Amazon? They display 3 reviews by default: good, medium, and bad. Please don't discourage other SO users by telling them something "sounds pointless"

Comment: @MichalSzyndel 1) Other SO users have their own point of view, so I by no means discourage them. 2) I expressed my feeling, provided the clarification why (**`at least in the context you've described`**)

Comment: @AndreyDeineko when a user with 11k karma tells a newbie to do something they can feel intimidated. Unless Fabian comes back and tells us what's the point I think we shouldn't make assumptions about anything!

Comment: @MichalSzyndel that is why there is my second part of the statement - `Why would you need this?`

Comment: Hey,I had two main reasons of trying to create a query like this.1. If I only suggest restaurants with a rating of 3 to the user, the other restaurants will have a very small chance of being picked, making their chance of being rated lower as well. I was thinking that I would create a sort of bias towards restaurants that already have a higher rating. To counteract this, to a certain extent, I would also suggest others. This would also test if the ratings really are a solid indicator for being chosen. 2. If I only have a small sample, then I still retain some variety.

Comment: Restaurants was just an example. I am kind of trying to find out if this is even possible and maybe a general direction I need to look into. :)  And thank you guys for already taking a look! Maybe it is in fact pointless... It was just something I was thinking could possibly create a problem.